Why in Deuteronomy does Moses introduce 200 new Mitzvot?
The Book of Numbers concludes the Torah narrative from the creation, through the Exodus, the Receiving of the Torah, the 40 years of the wilderness to make the Exodus generation go extinct, up to the moment of entering the promised land. It ends with the following verse:

"אֵלֶּה הַמִּצְוֺת וְהַמִּשְׁפָּטִים אֲשֶׁר צִוָּה יְהֹוָה בְּיַד־מֹשֶׁה אֶל־בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל בְּעַרְבֹת מוֹאָב עַל יַרְדֵּן יְרֵחוֹ׃"
"These are the commandments and laws that God commanded upon the Israelites, through Moses, on the steppes of Moab, at the Jordan near Jericho."

In the following book, Deuteronomy, Moses orients the new generation of settlers by providing a long recap of the period in the wilderness. In his speech, in addition to stories and complaints, he introduces 200 (!) additional Mitzvos, despite the aforementioned ending verse in Numbers.
I can't wrap my mind around this fact:

If those Mitzvos were already known to all, why weren't they all included in the previous books, for example, the multiple Mitzvos learned from שמע ישראל?
If they were not known and heard for the first time, why aren't they prefaced with "וידבר ה' למשה לאמר" or something similar to reflect their divinity and not Moses' addition? Alternatively, can we say that the Torah has changed to reflect the characteristics of the new generation, for example, the Mitzva to love God with all your heart?
If they were known only to Moses, why didn't he relay them to his generation? Didn't they put Teffilin or recite Shemah?


Mishneh Torah. According to R. Yishmael - derabannan, R. Akiva - deoraisa

@YDJ What the source?

When I was in yeshivah, someone referred that conclusion as result of lomdus in the name of R. Schlesinger. I have never investigated this point. However here's the write up by R. Jachter, which may answer your question. Part 1 https://www.koltorah.org/halachah/what-is-sefer-devarim-part-1-by-rabbi-chaim-jachter I think one need to verify the references, which might be off.

Part 2 https://www.koltorah.org/halachah/what-is-sefer-devarim-part-2-by-rabbi-chaim-jachter

I will use R. Chaim Jachter's comments on Sefer Devarim with added sources.
Moshe Rabbeinu delivered the speeches in Sefer Devarim, who wrote the speeches?  Using example of the curses in parashas Ki Savo, Megilla 31b implies that Moshe Rabbeinu composed Sefer Devarim. For example, Rashi clarifies:

Moshe spoke [the words] from the Mouth of the Might and was made into a messanger "Holy One Blessed be He said to me so", therefore [in Parashas Bechukosai it says]: "I will place, I will make you pay, I will send" - the One who is capable to do so. However, in the Mishneh Torah it is written "Hashem will hit, Hashem will attach to you". Moshe said [these words] on his own if the [Jewish people] transgress the commandments, Hashem will make them pay for it.

Tosafot (ad. loc.) clarify that Moshe Rabbeinu wrote it with Ru’ach HaKodesh, divine inspiration.  This means that Hashem influenced Moshe Rabbeinu in his composition of the speeches.  However, Tosafot does not state that Moshe Rabbeinu wrote Devarim with Nevu’ah, prophecy.  Moshe Rabbeinu did have input into the speech.  While it is difficult, if not impossible, to know where Hashem’s influence ended and Moshe Rabbeinu’s autonomy began, the Gemara clearly states that Moshe Rabbeinu had at least a measure of independence in the composition of the speeches recorded in Sefer Devarim.
Moreover, Moshe Rabbeinu certainly did not devise the Mitzvot that appear for the first time in Sefer Devarim.  Instead, what Moshe Rabbeinu is doing is presenting Mitzvot which he heard from Hashem at Har Sinai but until now were simply Torah SheBe’al Peh as noted in Shemot 34:32 with Chizkuni:

all the commandments that G-d had spoken to him about while he had been on Mount Sinai on his first and third stay on the Mountain, as well as all the commandments that He had communicated to him from Nissan when they had left Egypt until the twentieth of Iyar in the second year when they broke camp around the Mountain. However, according to the Talmud in tractate Gittin folio 60, the written Torah, i.e. in scroll form, he wrote down personally, one parchment at a time. When Moses made ready to leave this earth, he arranged these parchments in the order in which we read them nowadays according to the order he considered appropriate.

Also the introductions of the Ramban to Sefer Devarim:

Additionally, he (Moshe) proclaims commandments which have not been [previously] mentioned at all, such as the levirate marriage, the law concerning the defamation of a virgin bride, the divorcing of a wife, [the punishment of] plotting witnesses, and others besides. Now all these laws had in fact been declared to Moses, either on Sinai or in the Tent of Meeting within the first year [of the erection of the Tabernacle] before the affair of the spies. Nothing new was revealed to Moses in the plains of Moab [where he held this review of the Torah] except the words of the covenant, as is expressly stated there. It is for this reason that this book does not contain such statements as “And G-d spoke to Moses, saying:Command the children of Israel,” or “Speak to the children of Israel and say to them the following commandment” [since no new commandments were given in this book; they had all been previously declared to Moses either on Mount Sinai or in the Tent of Meeting]. These commandments, however, were not written in the preceding books wherein He speaks to those that came forth from Egypt. Perhaps this was because these commandments were obligatory only in the Land even though they affect personal conduct [and do not depend on the Land] such as Scripture mentions with reference to the drink-offerings; or it may be that because these were not of common occurrence, he mentioned them only to the generation, the inheritors of the Land.

For example, R. Jachter notes that in Sefer Shemot (20:14), Hashem commands us not to be jealous of our neighbor’s wife, his ox and donkey, and all that belongs to his neighbor.  However, in Sefer Devarim Moshe Rabbeinu formulates (according to the Pashtanim such as Ibn Ezra) the prohibition as forbidding jealousy of one’s neighbor’s wife, house, field, ox, and anything he has. in the Midbar we did not have homes and we did not have fields.  Now that we in Sefer Devarim are about to enter Eretz Yisrael the concern for jealousy of one’s neighbor’s house and field becomes very relevant.
The subject is discussed by Abarbanel to in his introduction to Sefer Devarim. Abarbanel clarifies that Hashem is the author of Sefer Devarim since Hashem is quoting Moshe Rabbeinu with His approval and even possibly edits his speeches for inclusion in the Torah (as for example, discussed here). Abarbanel fits beautifully with Chagigah 15b that teaches that Hashem cites the original Torah thoughts of the great Chachamim.  While Hashem undoubtedly influences the Chachamim (see Mishna, Yadayim 4:3), they also have some degree of autonomy.  Hashem cites the great Chachamim with approval just as He approvingly presents Moshe Rabbeinu’s speeches in Sefer Devarim.

You definitely earned +1, but I'm very confused. I understand that many deal with the contradiction but I don't see a coherent answer. I can't think of a reason NOT to include all of the Mitzvos in the previous Chumashim. You provide several "maybes" that contradict other accepted dogmas, like Mitzvas being universal.

@AlBerko I’m unsure why you have a problem with their introduction here as opposed to in the first four חומשים. The phrase וידבר ה׳ אל משה לאמר means that Hashem is the speaker of the commandments, and Mosheh’s transmission isn’t recorded. Here, Hashem’s giving isn’t recorded, but Mosheh’s transmission is. The reason why is a separate question. And how does the idea that Mosheh emphasized certain Mitzvot for the new generation, contradict any “accepted dogmas”? Emphasis isn’t the same as invention.

@AlBerko I think that the reason comes from pedagogy. Originally, Moshe envisioned that entire Torah development would be a job of the Leviim. However, when all Jews requested to learn the Torah, it had to be appropriately arranged. For example, the Pesach Haggada words of the son Chakham are in Devarim,  - because he learned Torah for 40 years, while Rasha, Tam and Sheeino yodea are in Shemos.

@QwertyCTRL. Because the last sentence of Numbers summarizes it as "those are the Mitzvos", and then the "repetition" in Deut adds 50% more.

If I understand, you resort to the claim, "there was a need for a different Torah for a different generation". Somewhat pathetic, don't you think?

@AlBerko not that. Every tribe has their way of thinking. Moshe intended to write a Torah for Leviim, but others had to get get something like Shulchan Aruch. When everyone decided to learn, it became a different text.

@AlBerko Not necessarily “those”, but “these”. That could refer to what comes before or afterward. Also, this isn’t the only place where such a phrase appears.

@AlBerko (re your last comment) That’s not the case. Rather, there may have been a need for Mosheh to EMPHASIZE certain pre-existing laws at that point in time. These laws existed already; either they were given before and the Torah only recorded them now (since their repetition wouldn’t be necessary for us), or they would have been taught before had it not been somehow better for Mosheh to include them in his speech. This isn’t some sort of theological dilemma.
